# request post returning an empty body

Tags: node.js, request

When I use curl or postman to post to a specific end point I am returned a body containing json.

However, when executing the following code, the endpoint returns no body.

```
    var options = {
    uri: 'http://example.com',
    method: 'POST',
    json: {
        type: "messages",
        access: req.params.ID
    },
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body); // Print the returned body
        res.json(body);
    }
});
```

Comment: is it confirmed server sends 200 status-code? because its possible some other code is returned.

Comment: how do you set req.params.ID ? Please post the route

Comment: You should post the curl command line that *does* work for you. Also, your custom headers should go in a `headers` object property instead of directly on the `options` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was stuck with the same issue.Include following lines in your app.js and your code will work.Do

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.set('json spaces', 1);
```

Dont forget to npm install body-parser --save.